# How to read a ROM file (SNES Game) in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm interested in emulation and would like to know how to read a ROM (NES/SNES Game) file to get some basic information on the ROM. Like game title or cart size. I can't seem to find anything on how to do this in Objective-C.

Thanks.

Comment: You know how to do it in C, C++, Java or any other languages, right?

Comment: @KazukiSakamoto No. But I am more familiar with Objective-C.

Comment: You're asking how to read binary files in Objective-C? or How to implement some emulator?

Comment: @KazukiSakamoto I don't want to implement and emulator, just how to read a ROM to get basic information about it. Like game title or cart size etc

Comment: You would just need to look up the details on the ROM format you want to use, then read the file and parse it using that specification.

Comment: Voting to reopen, clearly it wasn't 'too broad' as it was answered in a couple of lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can use NSData +dataWithContentsOfFile: to read a binary file.

```
NSData *romData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"path/foo.nes"];
const char *p = [romData bytes];
// p[0] is 'N'
// p[1] is 'E'
// p[2] is 'S'
// p[3] is 0x1a
```

And you can get title or something from the data pointer.

http://sadistech.com/nesromtool/romdoc.html

> The purpose of this document is to describe the setup and anatomy of a Nintendo (NES) ROM (.nes) file. It assumes an understanding of basic binary file handling (offsets, etc), hexadecimal notation, and binary